# how to reproduce byteArray representing audio file with angular

Tags: angularjs

I do rest calls from angular to my bussines logic class using camel to redirect from the call to the proper class.

I am using simpleCaptcha library for creating a captcha image. From the json object received from one bussiness class i am able to show the image with the tag img even receiving the image as byteArray.

I want to do the same with the audio file generated. But unfortunatelly sound tag looks only valid for URI.

Does anybody a way in angular for reproduce a byteArray which is a correct audio file wav??

Comment: I am not sure angularjs has to do anything with what you're trying to do. You should be asking (yourself) how to reproduce audio byte array [in the browser], and when you do this, you'd probably stumble on questions/answers like [this one: how-to-play-wav-audio-byte-array-via-javascript-html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151121/how-to-play-wav-audio-byte-array-via-javascript-html5)