# How to play a sound from bytes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, api

I am currently building an app where I want a specific sound to be played. The way I do this is that I call a Python API from JavaScript, which returns bytes.

My question is if it's possible to play a sound from bytes in JavaScript or is it possible for Python API to return playing audio instead of raw bytes?

Comment: It's possible to [play a sound from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151121/how-to-play-wav-audio-byte-array-via-javascript-html5) in JavaScript.

Comment: "return playing audio" makes no sense. You will have to implement a way to output the sound from client side.

Comment: If it's not possible to "return playing audio", is it possible to play sound from raw bytes?

Comment: Anderson Green, I've tried that but I always get "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data" error.